# Need a strategy for creating an XML document based on an XSD using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XSD file and have used XSD.exe to "reverse engineer" as class file.  In addition, I have used Entity Framework to "reverse engineer" a class for the data that will populate the XML document.  I can serialize the EF class but of course that doesn't match the XSD I must conform with.

I can enumerate through the EF class and populate the XSD class properties and then serialize...but that just seems wrong.

How can I populate the XML document without enumerating through the results from the EF class?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, your "XSD class" and your "EF class" have correlated data but the class definitions are at least slightly different?

Comment: If it's just an entity or two, write something that takes the entity writes it to xml and then (at least in test validates against the xsd). You can build an xml from an xsd easy enough populating it though is a different ball game, and a lot of code. For all but the simplest of entities trying to get a vanila xml to match the xml from a serialiser is painful and fragile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attributes from this page [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx) to control how you want to serialize your .NET Classes (in your case .NET Framework classes). Also check this list of articles on MSDN about serialization [XML and SOAP Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass).

Comment: And one more thing, if you will not reach what you want with serialization attributes - you can also use [ISerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx), it will be similar to "enumerating through the results from the EF class", but in right way which works well for .NET.